# How to extract data from an Status Array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation, mongodb-compass

Hy there, I'm using Compass as my tool for MongoDb.

Now, I have an array with valid statuses for a product and, once a product receive a new status I add it into the 'status' array.

What I need is to extract an Object with the dates when each status were added to the array, see the sample below:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("5e8f7ddb4af84bbb7431bc61"),
   Status: [`enter code here`
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5e8f7ddb4af84bbb7431bc62"), 
        Last: 'Added',
        Date: '2020-04-20 08:30:00'
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5e8f7ddb4af84bbb7431bc63"),
        Last: 'Proccessed',
        Date: '2020-04-20 09:30:00'
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5e8f7ddb4af84bbb7431bc64"),
        Last: 'Concluded',
        Date: '2020-04-20 14:00:00'
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5e8f7ddb4af84bbb7431bc65"),
        Last: 'Finished',
        Date: '2020-04-20 14:30:00'
    }
   ]
}
```

What I need is to extract an Object array for each Product like this:

```
[{
   _id: ObjectId("5e8f7ddb4af84bbb7431bc61"),
  Added: '2020-04-20 08:30:00',
  Proccessed: '2020-04-20 09:30:00',
  Concluded: '2020-04-20 14:00:00',
  Finished: '2020-04-20 14:30:00
}]
```

How can I achieve that using aggregation? Thanks in advance for your help.